# I want to create ASCII art but it gives me an error

Tags: python, ascii, index-error

I am trying to create ASCII Art but I am receiving an index error.

```
ASCII_CHARS = ['#','@','%', ',' ,'*','.', ':', ';']

def resize_image(image, new_width=100 ):
    width, height = image.size
    ratio = height / width
    new_height = int(new_width * ratio)
    resized_image = image.resize((new_width, new_height))
    return(resized_image)

def grayify(image):
    grayscale_image = image.convert("L")
    return(grayscale_image)
```

Why is "characters = "".join([ASCII_CHARS[pixel//25] for pixel in pixels])" giving me an index error

```
def pixels_to_ascii(image):
    pixels = image.getdata()
    characters = "".join([ASCII_CHARS[pixel//25] for pixel in pixels])
    return characters

def main(new_width=100):
    image = Image.open('wp1818453.jpg')
    new_image_data = pixels_to_ascii(grayify(resize_image(image)))
    pixel_count = len(new_image_data)
    ascii_image = "\n".join(new_image_data[i:(1+new_width)] for i in range(0, pixel_count))
    print(ascii_image)
    with open("ascii_image.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(ascii_image)
```

Is there a more efficient way to convert a jpg to terminal art?

Comment: Hello, did you looked at the value of pixel//25 when it failed ? Either via a try / except and a print() or via the debugger ? 255 // 25 = 10 which is far bigger than the size of ASCII_CHARS

Comment: BTW, do not hesitate to put a "minimal failing example" containing only the code we could copy paste to reproduce the issue, this will help us and sometime you may find your mistake just by doing it :)

Comment: @yota Thank you for the suggestion. I do not receive a value, I receive an error saying "unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'tuple' and 'int'"